# Android/Java - How to retrieve image from web service and show it

Tags: java, android

I'm using some services of a web service which usually returns JSON respones, but one service when I send the ID of a user returns a static GIF image (Not animated).

The procedure that I'm doing is:

1.Connect to web service using DefaultHttpClient
2.Convert the InputStream received to a String with this utilitary method:

```
public static String inputStreamToStringScanner(InputStream in) {

  Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(in);
  StringBuilder inputStreamString = new StringBuilder();
  while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    inputStreamString.append(fileScanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
  fileScanner.close();

  return inputStreamString.toString();
}
```

3.Storage the converted received String to process the server response.

For the Image Service, when I see the string converted, it begins like this:
"GIF89a?��?�� ..."

It's a static GIF file.

I'm not being able to show the image in a ImageView, I have tried different things that I found in the web:

```
public void onPhotoFinished (String responseData) {

  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  userImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

This is something else that I have also tried:

```
public void onPhotoFinished (String responseData) {

  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
  final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
  userImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

This also doesn't works:

```
public void onPhotoFinished (String responseData) {

  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
  userImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Finally, this doesn't work either:

```
public void onPhotoFinished (String responseData) {

  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(responseData.getBytes(), 0, responseData.getBytes().length);
  userImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

In Logcat I receive "decoder->decode returned false"

Nothing seems to work... any ideas of what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should surely be using a binary data structure for your image data , not string? Also if it's a gif then you'll need a god decoder - google for one.

Comment: Gif decoder even - damn iPhone autocorrect

Comment: Are you saying that BitmapFactory.decode doesn't work for GIF files? It's a static gif. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved it with FlushedInputStream and using directly the Input Stream, avoiding the conversion to String:

```
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream { 

public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
}

@Override
public long skip(long n) throws IOException { 

  long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
  while (totalBytesSkipped < n) { 
    long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
    if (bytesSkipped == 0L) { 
      int byteReaded = read();
      if (byteReaded < 0) {
          break; 
      } else {
          bytesSkipped = 1;
      }
    }
    totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
  }
  return totalBytesSkipped;
}

}
```

AND:

```
Bitmap bitmapResponseData = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
```

Regards